# Issue when deploying a PAYG VM with an Azure free account

Tags: azure, fortigate

I'm getting the error below when trying to launch the following PAYG VM: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/fortinet.fortinet-fortigate?tab=overview

I am using an Azure free account that gives me $200 free credit to be used on Azure for 30 days.

```json
{
  "code": "MarketplacePurchaseEligibilityFailed",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": "Offer with PublisherId: 'fortinet', OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: '0878401f-adb4-49c6-85f1-e3501ebadc08' The offer with PublisherId: 'fortinet', OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5' and PlanId: 'fortinet_fg-vm_payg_2023' cannot be used on selected subscription to purchase paid marketplace offers. Please choose another subscription or update this one to allow purchases. Learn more https://aka.ms/UpgradeFreeSub, https://aka.ms/Switch-Azure-Offer and https://aka.ms/Change-Credit-Card about updating subscriptions in Azure, Correlation Id: '0878401f-adb4-49c6-85f1-e3501ebadc08'.[{\"The offer with PublisherId: 'fortinet', OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5' and PlanId: 'fortinet_fg-vm_payg_2023' cannot be used on selected subscription to purchase paid marketplace offers. Please choose another subscription or update this one to allow purchases. Learn more https://aka.ms/UpgradeFreeSub, https://aka.ms/Switch-Azure-Offer and https://aka.ms/Change-Credit-Card about updating subscriptions in Azure, Correlation Id: '0878401f-adb4-49c6-85f1-e3501ebadc08'.\":\"StoreApi\"}]"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Marketplace purchase eligibilty check returned errors. See inner errors for details. "
}
```

Tried different times to launch this VM with the same error code. However, I had no problems launching other instances like an Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot be used on selected subscription to purchase paid marketplace offers. Please choose another subscription or update this one to allow purchases.

The error message you are encountering that you cannot purchase the **PAYG:** `Fortinet FortiGate Next-Generation Firewall (VM)` marketplace offer on your current `Azure free trial subscription`. This is because the `FortiGate VM` is a paid offer, and `free subscriptions` are not eligible to purchase paid offers.

I encountered the same error when attempting to create a `VM` using the **PAYG:** `Fortinet FortiGate Next-Generation Firewall (VM)` image from my `MPN` subscription.

[image]

To purchase the `FortiGate VM,` you will need to upgrade your `Azure free subscription` to a paid subscription.

Refer the **What can I buy with my monthly credit?** in this [Ms Doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/offers/ms-azr-0029p/) and also check same issue answered by `KarishmaTiwari-MSFT` in [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/524671/marketplacepurchaseeligibilityfailed-error-on-ente)"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After upgrading the Azure free subscription to a PAYG account, are the free credits still usable for this type of VM?

Comment: No, You cannot Purchase **FortiGate VM** with Azure free subscription.